# Problema con detección de colisiones y liberación de memoria de una lista de "enemigos" en C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, punteros

Aquí está el código respecto a liberar la memoria de una lista de enemigos y como he definido la estructura "ejercito", que representa a una lista de enemigos.

```
typedef struct Nodo
{
    Enemigo e;
    struct Nodo *sig;   //Enemigo e funciona perfectamente, solo quiero que 
                        //veais como he definido la estructura del ejercito
} *NodoPtr;

struct EjercitoRep
{
    NodoPtr cabecera;
};

void libera_ejercito (Ejercito e)
{
    while (e->cabecera->sig!=NULL)
    {
        NodoPtr borrar= e->cabecera->sig;
        e->cabecera->sig= borrar->sig;
        free(borrar);
    }
    free(e->cabecera);
}
```

Y aquí respecto a la colisión entre los enemigos y el personaje:

```
int colision_ejercito(Ejercito e, double x, double y, double w, double h)
{
    NodoPtr aux=e->cabecera;
    while(aux->sig !=NULL)
    {
        if (colision_enemigo(aux->sig->e,x,y,w,h))
        {
            return 1;
            aux=e->cabecera;
        }
        else{
             aux=aux->sig;
        }
        if (aux->sig==NULL){
            return 0;
        }
```

Y aquí el códido de colision_enemigo aunque ya digo que es algo irrelevante porque está función si funciona como debería:

```
int colision_enemigo(Enemigo e, double x, double y, double w, double h )
{
      if (solape_rectangulo(e->x,e->y,50,50,x,y,w,h)){
        return 1;  //La funcion solape_rectangulo funciona perfectamente
      }
      else{
        return 0;
      }
}
```

Aquí es como he llamado a las funciones en el main:

```
   if (colision_ejercito(apples,get_x_personaje(tux),get_y_personaje(tux),50,50))
            {
               libera_ejercito(apples);
               inserta_enemigo(apples,rand()%800,rand()%450);//El codigo de //inserta_enemigo funciona perfectamente
            }
```

El problema está en las funciones `libera_ejercito` y `colision_ejercito`. Cuando llamo a `libera_ejercito` en el main, y el programa detecta la colision entre el personaje y alguno de los enemigos de la lista, el programa crashea.
Y en `colision_ejercito`, el programa si detecta la colisión, pero solo con el primero de la lista(la insercion de `inserta_enemigo` es insercion por el principio, de tal manera que cuando inserta un nuevo enemigo este se añade al primero de la lista(despues de la cabecera))
Y por si lo necesitais, aqui esta como he definido la estructura enemigo y como libero su memoria:

```
struct EnemigoRep
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double vx;
    double vy;
    Imagen img;
};
void libera_enemigo(Enemigo e)
{
    Pantalla_ImagenLibera(e->img);
    free(e);
}
```

Ejercito está definido en "Ejercito.h" tal que así:

```
typedef struct EjercitoRep *Ejercito;
```

Funcion de insertar enemigo:

```
void inserta_enemigo(Ejercito e, double x, double y)
{
    NodoPtr nuevo=malloc(sizeof(struct EjercitoRep));
    nuevo->e=crea_enemigo(x,y);
    nuevo->sig=NULL;
    nuevo->sig=e->cabecera->sig;
    e->cabecera->sig=nuevo;
}
```

Comment: A menos que estemos hablando de una aplicación multihilo, en la que otro hilo pueda estar modificando las posiciones de los enemigos, si tienes un solo hilo, las variables tendrán los mismos valores en todas las iteraciones del bucle. Si no encontró ninguna colisión en la primera vuelta, ya no la encontrará en la segunda. Y si estás en una aplicación multihilo entonces tendrías que proteger seguramente el acceso a las variables mediante cerrojos. Todo sería más complejo. Y aún así.. siguiendo tu lógica la función `colision_ejercito()` no retornaría _hasta que_ se diera una colisión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como está el código, veo varias fuentes de problemas:

### Función `colision_ejercito()`

Aparentemente la misión de esta función es retornar 1 si hay una colisión entre el jugador y cualquiera de los enemigos, o bien cero si no hay ninguna colisión. Tal como estaba implementada en cambio no hace eso:

**Nota** El usuario modificó la pregunta posteriormente en base a mis comentarios, por lo que los dos puntos siguientes ya no son aplicables, aunque la solución que propongo sigue siendo más simple.

1. Primero porque sólo comprueba la colisión con el primer enemigo, ya que si ocurre esa colisión retorna 1 y si no (debido al `else`) retorna 0. No sigue mirando el resto de enemigos.
2. Segundo porque el código detrás del `if` (aunque debido al bug anterior no llega a ejecutarse nunca) también sería erróneo, ya que si `aux->sig` es NULL, eso implica que se ha terminado de examinar la lista de enemigos, en cuyo caso habría que retornar 0 en lugar de volver a empezar la lista por el principio. Volver a empezar implica que la función sólo puede retornar 1 y nunca 0, y que sólo retornará 1 cuando encuentre colisión, pero si no la hay permanece en un bucle infinito.

Esta sería la función corregida (a mi entender):

```
int colision_ejercito(Ejercito e, double x, double y, double w, double h)
{
    NodoPtr aux = e->cabecera;
    while(aux !=NULL)
    {
        if (colision_enemigo(aux->e, x, y, w, h)) 
        {
            return 1; 
        }
        aux = aux->sig;
    }
    // No se han detectado colisiones
    return 0;
}
```

### Función `libera_ejercito()`

Me cuesta seguir la ejecución de esta función y no soy capaz a ver claramente si tiene un bug. Tengo la impresión de que deja algún nodo sin liberar, o que puede fallar en la liberación del último, pero no lo veo claro. Propongo otra implementación ligeramente más sencilla (usa `e->cabecera` en lugar de `e->cabecera->sig` y de este modo evita también el `free(e->cabecera)` final).

Así:

```
void libera_ejercito (Ejercito e)
{
    while (e->cabecera!=NULL)
    {
        NodoPtr borrar = e->cabecera;
        e->cabecera = borrar->sig;
        free(borrar);
    }
    e->cabecera = NULL;
}
```

Por otro lado, este código estará liberando la lista de nodos, pero cada nodo contiene un puntero a un `Enemigo` que quedará sin liberar (y los recursos asociados al mismo, como su `img`), por lo que creo que lo correcto sería:

```
void libera_ejercito (Ejercito e)
{
    while (e->cabecera!=NULL)
    {
        NodoPtr borrar = e->cabecera;
        e->cabecera = borrar->sig;
        libera_enemigo(borrar->e);
        free(borrar);
    }
    e->cabecera = NULL;
}
```

### Función `inserta_enemigo()`

Observa que la función `libera_ejercito`, una vez ha terminado de liberar todo, deja `e->cabecera` con el valor `NULL`.

Por tanto, cuando en la función `inserta_enemigo()` llegas a la línea:

```
e->cabecera->sig=nuevo;
```

ya que `e->cabecera` es `NULL`, no puedes desreferenciarlo para acceder a su campo `sig`. Esta era la causa del *segfault*. La solución:

```
void inserta_enemigo(Ejercito e, double x, double y)
{
    NodoPtr nuevo = malloc(sizeof(struct EjercitoRep));
    nuevo->e = crea_enemigo(x,y);
    nuevo->sig = e->cabecera;
    e->cabecera = nuevo;
}
```

## Actualización final

A través de comentarios del usuario se me informa de que la aplicación sigue sin funcionar correctamente. La causa es que la estructura de lista enlazada `Ejercito` que manipulamos en las funciones antes descritas, es usada en otras partes del programa (por ejemplo, para pintar los enemigos que están en un ejército en la pantalla, o para crear un ejército inicialmente vacío). Estas otras funciones también necesitan ser modificadas.

El usuario me envía de forma privada el código. En su código la lista de enemigos (el Ejercito) tenía siempre un nodo inicial vacío (es decir, sin enemigo), aún cuando el ejército estaba vacío, y eso causaba problemas. Ahora un ejército vacío tiene `NULL` en el puntero a su cabecera, es decir, no tiene ningún nodo.

Estas son las restantes funciones que hay que modificar para que sean compatibles con la forma en que ahora se almancena la lista:

```
Ejercito crea_ejercito()
{
    Ejercito nuevo;
    nuevo=malloc(sizeof(struct EjercitoRep));
    nuevo->cabecera=NULL;
    return nuevo;
}

void mueve_ejercito(Ejercito e)
{
    NodoPtr aux=e->cabecera;
    while(aux!=NULL)
    {
        mueve_enemigo(aux->e);
        aux=aux->sig;
    }
}

void muestra_ejercito(Ejercito e)
{
    NodoPtr aux=e->cabecera;
    while (aux!=NULL)
    {
        if (aux->e) {
            muestra_enemigo(aux->e);
        }
        aux=aux->sig;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MiguelMartínezHernández Creo que está resuelto. Mira mi última actualización. Te sugiero también eliminar toda esta conversación a través de comentarios para dejar la pregunta y la respuesta más limpias. Yo voy a borrar mis comentarios.

Comment: Vale, finalmente me funciona. Te marco la respuesta y muchas gracias. Perdón por todas las molestias que te he causado que no han sido pocas xD